# How to display data on a data grid in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I AM Writing a WPF Application for music data analysis. I have a Database where i store some song informations and i want to display them in a data grid.

This is the Object class i want to display;

```cs
public class SongData
{
    public uint Id;
    public BitmapImage Cover;
    public string Title;
    public string Artist;
    public string Album;
    public TimeSpan Duration;
    public TimeSpan Cue;
    public string Key;
    public bool Available;
    public string FilePath;
    public decimal Bpm;
}
```

this is the Datagrid i designed:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Songs" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{DynamicResource bg_dark}" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource accent_dark}" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource text}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{DynamicResource bg_dark}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource frame_dark}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5,0,0.5,0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cover" Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Cover}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding FilePath}" Width="500" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Artist}" Width="500" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Album" Binding="{Binding Album}" Width="350" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Binding="{Binding Duration}" Width="100" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BPM" Binding="{Binding Bpm}" Width="100" CanUserSort="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" Width="100" CanUserSort="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and this is the code behind filling the dataGrid:

```cs
public partial class Frame_Library : Page
{
    public Frame_Library()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Frame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var DbSongs = DatabaseHelper.GetAllSongs();

        DataGrid_Songs.ItemsSource = DbSongs;
    }
}
```

i already checked: the DbSongs variable is a List and i can read the Properties of an item in the list and print them to the Debug output.

The problem ist, none of the data on in the DataGrid even tho the grid displays the right amount of lines for each entry in the list.

This is the Errormessage is get:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Cover' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Cover; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FilePath' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=FilePath; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Artist' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Artist; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Album' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Album; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Duration' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Duration; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Bpm' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Bpm; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=7999906)'. BindingExpression:Path=Key; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=7999906); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Cover' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Cover; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FilePath' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=FilePath; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Artist' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Artist; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Album' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Album; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Duration' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Duration; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Bpm' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Bpm; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found on 'object' ''SongData' (HashCode=17744591)'. BindingExpression:Path=Key; DataItem='SongData' (HashCode=17744591); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? I might be missing something but your question doesnt really state what the issue is, or what your results were and how they differ from your expectations. You shouldnt be setting the ItemsSource through equals "=". It should also be done through binding. That is one of the only things I see off in the code provided.

Comment: For data binding, the members of view model must be properties.

Comment: The solution is very simple actually. Just define setters for your SongData

So: public string Title { get; set; }
And your done